# Snowflake: Transpose rows as columns

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am stuck on what seems to be an extremely simple use case,

I've a data like below:

```
|id | json 
________________
|1  | {"a":"1"}
|1  | {"a":"2"}
|2  | {"a":"3"}
```

all I want to do is below:

```
|id | all 
________________
|1  | {"a":"1"}, {"a","2"}
|2  | {"a":"2"}
```

or even below is good enough:

```
|id | type1          | type2      |
__________________________________
|1  | {"a":"1"}      |{"a","2"}
|2  | {"a":"2"}      |            |
```

please note that there is no `aggregation` needed hence.

I tried several things, but can't seem to get correct syntax or may be the strategy to achieve this within snowflake?
Any ideas?

**Update**
below seems to be doing what I want, but are there better or simple ideas?

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    LISTAGG(
    TO_VARCHAR(OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('a', col1), ',') AS OBJ
FROM SCHEMA.TABLE
WHERE 
    *my conditions*
GROUP BY 
    id
;
```

Comment: Depending on what the input data type is, first example looks like [`object_agg()`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/object_agg) or the `listagg()` you used. You can get the second one with [`pivot()`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/pivot). What do you mean by *note that there is no aggregation needed*?

Comment: @Zegarek thanks for your comment, problem with using `object_agg` is the value of the column id is going to be duplicate, hence if I use `object_agg(id,json)`, it will not allow because of duplicate key. listagg seems to do the trick

Comment: no aggregation simply meant, I do not have anything to aggregate, I just need to transpose all the different values in column json against a unique value of column id.

Comment: What do you understand by *aggregation* and why do you think you don't need it? Both `listagg()` and `object_agg()` are aggregate functions, while pivot does aggregation inside. What you just did above with `list_agg()` is aggregation into groups of rows sharing an `id`. About undesired `object_agg()` deduplication: good point. Normally in this case it would be nice to use a json array and collect each k:v pair into an element, but this doesn't seem to be an option here.

Comment: You could also consider [`array_agg()`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_agg) to retain the original type of each element and simplify splitting/subscripting later. That would result in an *array of json*, not a *single json with a json array in it*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you collect these k:v pairs into an array, you retain the original type and simplify subscripting

```sql
SELECT 
    id, 
    ARRAY_AGG(OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('a', col1)) AS OBJ
FROM SCHEMA.TABLE
WHERE *my conditions*
GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: this looks like a little better for my strategy

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `PIVOT`, but first you need to assign a unique sequential number to each row with a partition using `row_number()` :

```
select p.*
from   ( select *,
                row_number() over (partition by id order by json) as rn
         from   mytable
       )
pivot  ( MAX(json) for id in (1, 2) ) p (id, type1, type2);
```

Results :

```
ID  TYPE1       TYPE2
1   {"a":"1"}   {"a":"3"}
2   {"a":"2"}
```

Comment: this looks like a good strategy, let me see how it goes

Comment: You missed the part with replacing the `"b"` key with `"a"`. Why do you need `row_number()`?

Comment: `row_number()` used here to distinguish the rows, which prevents the Aggregate function `min()` from only returning one item for each id.